# In 1997, what would the likely Paris–Tokyo route be? Generally, where to gain information on historic routes?

Tags: aviation-history, routing

Today you would likely via Dubai, or perhaps take one of the long flights say Zurich -> NRT.

If I'm not mistaken Dubai came to it's current position in early 2000s, so in the 90s it was not the typical international hub it is today. And the longer Europe -> Asia legs were not common.

What would have been a typical route in the middle nineties?

More generally, is there an "expedia of the past"?

As a child (70s) I know all the typical routes, say, UK - Australasia in that era, but they have all changed drastically. Is there any way to find or know the typical routes of past decades? (Other than asking now-old airline staff!)

Comment: (there are a number of similar excellent questions on the site, eg https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53584/what-was-the-flight-route-from-new-york-to-paris-that-air-france-took-in-1955 )

Comment: It's a shame this knowledge is being lost forever.

Comment: There are direct flights …

Comment: @Antzi in 1997 ??

Comment: I don’t know. I meant today.

Comment: I see. Yes, I've flown that route many times, today.  Notice the question at hand (notice first two words) is about 1997.  Cheers.

Comment: The first sentence of the question seems to imply that a direct flight is not usual, mentioning the Zurich (?) Narita

Comment: hi @Antzi  pls read the title. the question is about in 1997.  thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want for this question,and other similar ones, are old copies of "The ABC World Airways Guide" .

This image, from a 1991 copy, gives you some sense of what was contained within it https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1E9sPe3jKGQ/Ur7xyNPWerI/AAAAAAAAMTI/9T9ARGBdCDE/s1600/PK+pia+pakistan+1991+1.jpg .

It showed you the points at which a flight landed but it didn't indicate the routes between those points ... I think it's the former rather than the latter you want ?

From googling around I can see large libraries which hold copies of these.

UPDATE: This blog post https://airline-memorabilia.blogspot.com/2013/12/abc-world-airways-guide-1991.html contains a number of other images from a 1991 copy of the guide.

UPDATE2: This is also an amazing, to me at least, resource http://www.timetableimages.com/ttimages/complete/complete.htm .

Comment: Glaucon, this is an incredibly useful answer.  Thank you!  (I'm a bit surprised there is not more interest in this question!)  Again thanks!!!

Comment: Fattie - It's certainly stuff that interests me but I guess it's not for everyone ;-) I remember thumbing through ABC World Airways Guide. Apart from the timetables there were lots of fascinating footnotes about obscure places ... rather geeky but then I am !

Comment: Heh - such is life